# CSS Weird fixed position bug with textarea overflow

Tags: css

I'm probably missing something small, but I'm having trouble figuring it at the moment:

I've got an doc with the following div at the tail

```
<div style="position:fixed; display:block; width:300px; height:100px; top:30px; left:30px; background:#333;">
    <textarea>
        asdf
    </textarea>
</div>
<canvas width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

Whenever I enter a few dozen lines of text into the textarea, when I backspace my fixed positioning goes off the hook and pushes everything to the right / down about 250-350px.  Note that this specifically happens when backspacing into a line break.  Very weird bug (via chrome).

Comment: `display: block;` doesn't usually mix all that well with defining both width and height, you should use `display: inline-block;` for that normally, still it should work with a `position: fixed;` in the mix, you should report a bug to the chrome developers if one is not already reported, in the meantime I suggest you try other positionings, or try wrapping your textarea in some other element

Comment: try to replicate outside of your doc -- put on JSFiddle also ( for others to test )

Comment: testing this out on jsfiddle now

Comment: While I try to recreate this on jsfiddle - I noticed that when html5 canvas is displayed element, I have this issue.  When I remove or even display:none canvas, the issue goes away.

Comment: I actually so far haven't been able to recreate this in jsfiddle; i've got every element matched.

Comment: I've determined the issue surprisingly has to do with canvas width / height attributes - results coming shortly!

Comment: Pushed to chrome bugs - http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/mac/a3jmqt7qISw

Comment: I am also having the same issue.

Comment: Michael - if you've figured this out, would you be so kind as to post an answer to your own question, showing the fix - and mark it as correct, so that this question falls out of the "Unanswered" section - and the solution is clearer to other searchers, such as Ed?

Comment: @TroyAlford - No go yet, Chrome hasn't cleared the bug.  Not sure if there's big enough request for them to flag it higher.

Answer (score 0):

try this: (no spaces between textarea)

```
<div style="position:fixed; display:block; width:300px; height:100px; top:30px; left:30px; background:#333;">
    <textarea>asdfWhenever I enter a few dozen lines of text into the textarea, when I backspace my fixed positioning goes off the hook and pushes everything to the right / down about 250-350px. Note that this specifically happens when backspacing into a line break. Very weird bug (via chrome).</textarea>
</div>
<canvas width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```